# Can't Access Quote Line Items through Quote Object in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, quote, quotelineitem

When I go to create a new process in Process Builder on the Quote Object, why are Quote Line Items not an option under field selection? See image below - The 'Line Items' that shows is just a count field of the number of line items on a particular quote.

[image]

Quote Line Items definitely have a parent-child relationship with Quotes.  If I select Quote Line Item as the object to start PB on, I can then access the Quote parent object, but not the other way around.

I want to start a Process based on when a Quote has been accepted, but only if the line item product name contains certain words.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query child records from process builder.  You'll have to use a record-triggered Flow, since flows can query and loop through child records.

Comment: Thanks @David! I'm looking to update a field if certain wording is contained within the Product Name of the Quote Line Item within a particular Quote - I'm not really sure how to create the flow to do this. Are you able to provide me with an example?

Comment: You'll have to build loops and use formula variables in the Flow, so look for tutorials on those.  On a different tack, a rollup tool like Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries might be able to rollup the line item count to the quote (depending on the complexity of your wording), then you could use process builder on the quote's rollup field.

Comment: I have DLRS, but I don't need the count of QuoteLineItems to a particular quote - I need to know if a certain string exists within the Product.Name field of a QuoteLineItem within a Particular Quote.  Thanks for the advice, I'll look up Loops.

Comment: You can use the count as part of your PB condition -- Quote is approved and line item count > 0, since the count would indicate how many line items' product names have the wording.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - That's not a bad idea either. Thanks for the suggestion!